# Python/Pandas: How to modify the data in a column of a dataframe and append the list of transformations applied to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column that looks like this:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Good & Bad',' Good & (okay) Bad ','Good PVT '], }, 
                  columns=['Name'])
```

I want the output dataframe to look like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Good & Bad', 'Good & Bad', 'Good & (okay) Bad','Good & (okay) Bad','Good PVT ','Good PVT '] ,'Modified Name': ['Good & Bad', 'Good AND Bad', 'Good & (okay) Bad','Good AND Bad','Good PVT','Good Private'],
                   'Transformations applied': ['None','AND','None', ['paran','AND'],'None', 'PVT']}, 
                  columns=['Name', 'Modified Name','Transformations applied'])
```

I've been iterating over each row of dataframe and appending the original row and then adding the transformed row

The function I've been trying is

```
def Transformation:
    TA =[]
    m=  ''   
    text = str(text)
    res = re.findall(r'\(.*?\)',text)
    if len(res)>0:
       m = re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]","",text)
       TA.append('paran')
    if "&" in text.upper():
       if m ==''
          m=text.replace('&','and')
          TA.append('AND')
       else:
          m=m.replace('&','and')
          TA.append('AND')

   
return m, TA
```

I have many number of cases and the dataframe is also quite large.

The way I've written doesn't seem lika effective way to do it.

Can someone please suggest how to do it effectively in python?

Comment: Is the value of column `Transformations applied` already known and what's the transformation rule?

Comment: No it's not already known. I just populated to make it easy